# Split a string by another string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

I've been using the `Split()` method to split strings, but this only appears to work if you are splitting a string by a character. Is there a way to split a `string`, with another string being the split by parameter?

I've tried converting the splitter into a character array, with no luck.

In other words, I'd like to split the `string`:

> THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX

by `xx`, and return an array with values:

> THE, QUICK, BROWN, FOX

Comment: For future concerns:  One of the below comment interested me so I decided to open a [discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/372293/307733) on software engineering concerning the _nonintuitive_ (but right) way to do it in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1519, accepted):

In order to split by a string you'll have to use the [string array overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx).

```
string data = "THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX";

return data.Split(new string[] { "xx" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: I actually ended up changing my answer to this for 2 reasons:

#1:  To handle the splits I want to do I would need to use Regex.Escape, because my split string will often contain asterisks, etc.

#2:  While this program I'm writing needs no real optimization, there does appear to be additional overhead involved with using the Regex Split method.

Comment: In my defense, Jon Skeet suggested somewhere to use Regex when splitting strings with strings as a seperator,  and I have to admit when he suggest sth. I tend to believe it seldom is bad advice.  

('Although chances are you want split
by string rather than character, in which case you'll want to look atRegex.Split')

Comment: @Peter: In that post Jon is suggesting it because the poster does not have a fixed delimiter; he is looking to split strings separated by "more than one space" (meaning 2+). For strings delimited by a *pattern* rather than a *value*, RegEx is a great (well, the *only*) option. For fixed-value delimiters, it introduces needless overhead. Try running a test; as the number of operations increases, RegEx ends up taking somewhere around ~10x as long as a corresponding `string.Split`.

Comment: I come from Python to C#. Python supports string split by another string. And I frequently need to come back to this question for a simple answer to `string[] Split(string pattern)`, which is the most natural usage I could think of yet it isn't there. I wrote C before so I am used to char arrays but I still hate to see `char[]` popping up in a C# code because it suddenly drags my attention from stream level to byte level. Anybody know why C# library guys designed the Split method like this? If there is a good reason, I can probably try to appreciate it despite the inconvenience.

Comment: This snippet ranks very high on the the list of things I'd be ashamed of to show to non C# developers.

Comment: Why the hell can't we just do `data.Split("xx")`?

Comment: You could save some characters and shut ReSharper up by doing this : `data.Split(new [] { "xx" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`. If this is used often it might be worth creating your own split method. Something like

`public static string[] Split(this string text, string[] seperator)
 {
 return text.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.None);
 }`

Comment: @mcont We can split by string in .net core. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56284791/1248177)

Comment: @mcont I try this but it not work it must be char

Comment: Even with the understanding that having both `Split(char)` and `Split(string)` makes `Split(null)` ambiguous, why then not use a distinct method name? Have `Split(char)` + family and `Split_S(string)` or whatever + family and let them eat cake

Answer (score 158):

edit: See @Danation's answer for newer/less versbose overload

---

There is an [overload of Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) that takes strings.

```
"THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX".Split(new [] { "xx" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You can use either of these StringSplitOptions

- **None**  - The return value includes array
  elements that contain an empty string
- **RemoveEmptyEntries** - The return value
  does not include array elements that
  contain an empty string

So if the string is "THExxQUICKxxxxBROWNxxFOX", `StringSplitOptions.None` will return an empty entry in the array for the "xxxx" part while `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will not.

Comment: It does not quite "take" strings. It expects an array of chars, you simply used the literal constructor for this.

Comment: @SvenMawby Nah, it "literally" has an "overload" for an "array" of "strings".  `Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)`

Answer (score 93):

```
Regex.Split(string, "xx")
```

is the way I do it usually.

---

Of course you'll need:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

or :

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(string, "xx")
```

but then again I need that library all the time.

Comment: @Brandon: While I'm usually cautioning against premature optimization, you should be aware that a `RegEx.Split` is quite a bit more costly than a simple `String.Split` because of the regular expression overhead.

Comment: If you want to split by an arbitrary string, use `Regex.Escape` on the string first, this will escape any regex meta-characters.

Comment: one of the key advantages that may pay for overhead is ability to provide string comparison setting

Answer (score 52):

There's an overload of [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) for this:

```
"THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX".Split(new [] {"xx"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: The only answer which removes the needless array type declaration.

Answer (score 31):

I generally like to use my own extension for that:

```
string data = "THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX";
var dataspt = data.Split("xx");
//>THE  QUICK  BROWN  FOX 


//the extension class must be declared as static
public static class StringExtension
{   
    public static string[] Split(this string str, string splitter)
    {
        return str.Split(new[] { splitter }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

This will however lead to an Exception, if Microsoft decides to include this method-overload in later versions. It is also the likely reason why Microsoft has not included this method in the meantime: At least one company I worked for, used such an extension in all their C# projects.

It may also be possible to conditionally define the method at runtime if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Alternatively, use `params string[] splitter` as the second parameter and change `new[] {splitter}` to `splitter` to support multiple delimiters.

Answer (score 19):

As of .NET Core 2.0, there is an override that takes a string.

So now you can do `"THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX".Split("xx")`.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-2.0#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_

Answer (score 17):

The previous answers are all correct. I go one step further and make C# work for me by defining an **extension method** on String:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string[] Split(this string toSplit, string splitOn) {
        return toSplit.Split(new string[] { splitOn }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }
}
```

That way I can call it on any string in the simple way I naively expected the first time I tried to accomplish this:

```
"a big long string with stuff to split on".Split("g str");
```

Answer (score 8):

```
string data = "THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX";

return data.Replace("xx","|").Split('|');
```

Just choose the replace character carefully (choose one that isn't likely to be present in the string already)!

Comment: @MasoudHosseini: Please read the complete answer; there's already a disclaimer.

Comment: @kobe: Because it's a terrible hack.

Comment: Works fine, but it is dangerous for generic methods

Comment: Posting explanations like, "It's a terrible hack" or "a bad answer" are not helpful.  It's simply an opinion without explanation.  Instead, stating something like "It's unnecessary to both scan the string for replacements and then scan for split characters since it leads to poor performance." would be a better way to explain yourself.  Too many programmers act this way.  :(

Comment: What if the string contains the `|` char already, for this reason I think it's dangerous to use.

Comment: @amd: The answer is a template, and doesn't necessarily enforce the use of `|`. I hope you read the footnote disclaimer and the rest of the comments here.

Comment: I'm using this XD, too bad .NET didn't have overload for single string split problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create this function first.

```
string[] xSplit(string str, string sep) {
    return str.Split(new [] {sep}, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

Then use it like this.

```
xSplit("THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX", "xx");
```

Answer (score -2):

This is also easy:

```
string data = "THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX";
string[] arr = data.Split("xx".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: But this would also split `"THExQUICK"` where we do not want it to be splitted

Comment: Thanks Rafalon: yes, Greg's is the best answer: data.Split(new string[] { "xx" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Answer (score -5):

The easiest way is to use `String.Replace`:

```
string myString = "THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX";
mystring = mystring.Replace("xx", ", ");
```

Or more simply:

```
string myString = "THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX".Replace("xx", ", ");
```

Comment: As it is, this won't return an array (as the question asks for), just a string with commas where the `xx`'s were.

Comment: And not only that if the string contained additional comma's you would not be able to split out the words correctly.

Comment: He is onto something though. If you also chain it with a split. Doubt it is effective, but it is more readable..
var myStrings = "THExxQUICKxxBROWNxxFOX".Replace("xx", "|").Split('|');

Comment: @Terje. What if there are already some "|" in the start string ?