# split string with regular expression by elements

Tags: c#, regex, string, split

What is a c sharp option to split this string:

```
"['A','B', ''],['A','D', 'F'],['A','G', 'G']"
```

into list of strings:

```
"['A','B', '']"
"['A','D', 'F']"
"['A','G', 'G']"
```

Comment: Is `"['],']"` a valid input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're better off writing a simple parser than trying to match balanced text with a regular expression:

```
var str = "['A','B', ''],['A','D', 'F'],['A','G', 'G']";
var topLevelLists = new List<string>();
var arrStart = -1;
var nesting = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != str.Length; ++i) {
    if (str[i] == '[') {
        if (nesting == 0) {
            arrStart = i;
        }
        ++nesting;
    }
    else if (str[i] == ']') {
        if (nesting <= 0) {
            // Error, ']' without matching '[' at i
            break;
        }
        --nesting;
        if (nesting == 0) {
            topLevelLists.Add(str.Substring(arrStart, i - arrStart + 1));
        }
    }
}
if (nesting > 0) {
    // Error, unmatched '[' at arrStart
}

// topLevelLists => [ "['A','B', '']", "['A','D', 'F']", "['A','G', 'G']" ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex: `(?<=\]),` to split by comma which ispreceded by `]`.

The code is:

```
String input = "['A','B', ''],['A','D', 'F'],['A','G', 'G']";
String pattern = @"(?<=\]),";

var split = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your separator is `],` (comma comes after the the bracket `]`) you can use a tricky way:

```
var parts = string.Join("]" + char.MaxValue, input
           .Split(new[] {"],"}, StringSplitOptions.None))
           .Split(char.MaxValue);
```

This approach simply replace all commas that comes after square brackets with a *temporary* char (`char.MaxValue` in this case) and then `Split` the string by that charachter.

Answer (score 0):

The "pure Regex" answer is like this:

```
        string str = "['A','B', ''],['A','D', 'F'],['A','G', 'G']";
        string[] strs =
            Regex.Matches(str, @"(\[.*?\])")
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value)
                 .ToArray();
```

which is more tolerant of different - or even mixed - separators between the bracketed groups, such as comma-space or space rather than just a comma. If your input string is well-defined then this won't be an issue, but I prefer to be able to handle inputs which might come from different sources and might not quite conform.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand, you want to split String with another String.
Split String by String is done as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string)

For your question - split it by `],`