# Isolate a pattern using RegEx match

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of the form

```
 _statistics = 
      [
    { Some JSON text here },
.
.
.
];
```

Basically, I need the text within '[' and '];' . How can i isolate this using RegEx match.

Comment: [Use a parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22773121/21475)! :-)

Comment: So...I presume "Some JSON text here" would be JSON?  As in, the potential for `{ "foo": [ 1, [ "a" ]] }`?  I believe recursion like that will get in the way of regex.

Comment: yes.. the JSON text spills over several lines.. but irrespective of what text is between '[' and '];', i need to get it

Comment: [`(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])`](http://regex101.com/r/bL1rO5) works, but will fail if you have something like: `[ { "string" : "[I'm in a bracket]" } ]`.

Comment: @Sam looks like it gives a positive match.. but in C#, i'm not able to isolate the text.. anyways, should solve my real problem:) pls Answer the question so I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really the **best** solution, but anything more intensive and you might as well be using a full JSON parsing library.

```
(?<=\[)[^\]]+(?=\])
```

This looks behind for an open bracket (`(?<=\[)`), then matches 1+ *non* bracket characters (`[^\]]+`), and looks ahead for the closing bracket `(?=\])`.  You could optionally forget the lookarounds, and use a capture group instead:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]
```

The reason this isn't the **best** solution, is because it literally looks for text between `[` and `]`.  So JSON like `[ { "string" : "[I'm in a bracket]" } ]` would return `{ "string" : "[I'm in a bracket` as a match.

Example: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bL1rO5)