# How i can get input from user where the two inputs are separated by spaces?

Tags: c#

How i can get input from user where the two inputs are separated by space?
I tried doing this with Conver.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());But it is showing format exception.
Please tell whether there is some other way of getting input from user.
Please help!
Thank you for reading my problem.

Ex:
input:
10 2
input is in the above format.
The value 10 & 2 should be stored in different variables.

Comment: Read input in as a string and split it with space.

Comment: I presume the problem isn't getting the input from the user but parsing it into two variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Split A String By Another String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string)

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] inputs =TextBoX1.Text.Split(" ");
String first = inputs[0].ToString();
String second = inputs[1].ToString();
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer to include an explanation of your code? It helps the reader more than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] inputs =Console.ReadLine().Split(null);

int input1=TryParse(inputs[0]);
int input2=TryParse(inputs[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine()` will only return values once the user enters a new-line (IE. presses return).

To get what you're after, you might consider using `Console.ReadKey()` or `Console.Read()` in order to get individual characters.

Such that your code would look something like:

```
public int GetNextNumber()
{
    char nextChar;
    string numberString = string.Empty;
    while (!char.IsWhiteSpace(nextChar = (char)Console.Read())
        numberString += nextChar;
    int result;
    if (!int.TryParse(numberString, out result))
        throw new InvalidCastException("Specified string is not an integral");
    return result;
}
```

You can then use that method to read each individual number from the console, as the user enters it.
You could also do a `Console.ReadLine()` and split the resulting string to get the numbers like some of the others suggested

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Because I do not see the actual code you tried I can just assume you did something like:

```
int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

and the actual input was "10 2", which is a string.
The error occured when the method tried to convert the empty space to an int.

You need to save the input as a string variable, then split the string variable with empty spaces as seperator. You can save the result as an string array (string[]) and then convert each array element of the string[] to an int.

Reading the input for your code:

```
string input = Console.Readline();
```

Split method for your code:

```
string[] stringArray= input.Split(' ');
```

Convert each string to an int for your code:

```
List<int> integerList = new List<int>();

foreach (string str in array)
{
    integerList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(str));
}
```

Note, that this would also work for an input with more than 2 numbers, for example "10 2 17 3 19 27" and you do not need an own variable for each input part because you add each value to a list. Why a list ? because the size is dynamic. Your problem would also work with an array instead of a list because at the moment you split your string you know the size the intArray would need but a list is more comfortable.