# List and array comparison

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement wherein I have a value in Viewbag.Keyword like "Johnson and Jen" so I have to split this value and compare it with List.

I was trying the below code but facing error some or the other way(eg; this is char not string and so on) and it doesn't look like smart coding as per latest functionalities available in framework 4.5

```
var str = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Keyword);
string[] str1 = str.Split(' ');

for (int j = 0; j < str1.Length;j++)
{
    string str2 = Convert.ToString(str[j]);
    if (result.Document.ContactName.IndexOf(str2, 
        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
```

Note: "ContactName" is string.
Please help with some latest code which improves performance.

Comment: Should not str[j] be str1[j]? And where is the List you want to compare to?

Comment: At `str[j]` you surely mean `str1[j]`. And the `Convert` isn't necessary there as `str1[j]` already is a string.

Comment: do you want to check whether the  `Viewbag.Keyword`in the list?

Comment: if keyword is "Johnson and Jen" and you want to split them into 2, I would recommend `str.Split(new string[] { " and " },StringSplitOptions.None);` so you get "Johnson" & "Jen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to check for the exact match of the words you get by splitting the keyword string using a white space against the contact name property from the collection then you can use a regular expression to do that.

The regular expression is of the form `\bTheWordGoesHere\b` where `\b` is the word boundary delimiter

Check this sample code snippet.

```
var keyword = "Johnson and Jen";
var arr = keyword.Split(' ');
var contactName = "Johnson anderson mobile";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    var pattern = string.Format("\\b{0}\\b", arr[i]);
    if (Regex.IsMatch(contactName, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        // do something
        Console.WriteLine("contactName contains the word \"" + arr[i] + "\"");
    }
}
```

[rextester link](http://rextester.com/NBWTD39054)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linq` to check if `result.Document.Name` `contains` a word from array.

```
var str = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Keyword);
string[] str1 = str.Split(' ');
var names = str1.Where(x => (result.Document.ContactName.Contains(x))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare those names are on that string like below,

> Remember comparison is case sensitive

```
var str = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Keyword);
string[] str1 = str.Split(' ');

if(str1.Any(result.Document.ContactName.Contains)){
    //Do Something
}
```

Example -

```
var str = "Johnson and Jen";
string[] str1 = str.Split(' ');
string result = "Jendasdbnoahsdasnd"; // I assume your ContactName result is like this
if (str1.Any(result.Contains)) // This gives true because Jen in the string
{
  //Do Something
}
```

But, for the `string result = "jendasdbnoahsdasnd"` it gives false because of the case.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code for doing the same using clean code

```
var str = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Keyword);
var possibleNames = str.split(' ');

//to check if any match exists
bool anyMatch = possibleNames.Any(n => n.Equals(result.Document.ContactName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

//get matched names
var matchedNames = possibleNames.Where(n => n.Equals(result.Document.ContactName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

//do whatever you want with matchedNames now
var array = matchedNames.ToArray();
var list = matchedNames.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string `"Johnson and Jen"` by using another string i.e. `" and "` this will exactly give you the names which will be appropriate to check against the contact name.

You can check about the `Split` function [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string)

To check whether a property contains a specified string or not you can use the `IndexOf` method - a simple sample code snippet is given below, you can run this sample code snippet [here](http://rextester.com/PDTJ89388).

```
var keyword = "Johnson and Jen";
var arr = keyword.Split(new string[] { " and " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var contactName = "Johnson";
for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (contactName.IndexOf(arr[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        // do something
        Console.WriteLine("contactName contains the string \"" + arr[i] + "\"");
    }
}
```

The code snippet for your scenario would be as follows and in your code you don't need the unnecessary type casting i.e. `string str2 = Convert.ToString(str[j]);` because `str[j]` is already a string

```
var keyword = Convert.ToString(ViewBag.Keyword);
var arr = name.Split(new string[] { " and " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    if (result.Document.ContactName.IndexOf(arr[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Using the `StringComparison` parameter with its value as `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` will do a case insensitive search

Comment: Well I have already tried most of the scenarios, I need exact match of the word from the collection.

Current issue 
eg: Contact Name **"Johnson anderson mobile"**

Here results  returned are "Johnson anderson" --> **"anderson"** because it matches **"and"**, which I don't require, please help me with the fix.