# How to get the full string element of a dicom item with fo-dicom?

Tags: c#, string, dicom, fo-dicom

I'm trying to get a string of a radiation therapy plan in a dicom file with fo-dicom. Doesn't seem to be that hard for you, but I'm stucking because I cannot find the right command.

I was filtering the plan e.g. for the `Leaf/Jaw Positions`. The string value shown in VS debugging mode is *"-35//35"* and I find it in my DICOM Editor too. But the output only gives me the value *-35*. My code is like

```
var Leaf = file.Dataset.Get<Dicom.DicomSequence>(Dicom.DicomTag.BeamSequence).Items[0].
            Get<Dicom.DicomSequence>(Dicom.DicomTag.ControlPointSequence).Items[0].
            Get<Dicom.DicomSequence>(Dicom.DicomTag.BeamLimitingDevicePositionSequence).Items[0].
            Get<string>(Dicom.DicomTag.LeafJawPositions);
```

So with this I only get the mentioned first value. By changing the last `Get<string>()` to `Get<Dicom.DicomElement>()` or something else in debugging overwatch I can see the whole string again, but can't print it.

As I looked up here [C# Split A String By Another String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string) or [Easiest way to split a string on newlines in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net) I tried it with editing my code to

```
string Leaf = file.Dataset.Get<Dicom.DicomSequence>(Dicom.DicomTag.BeamSequence).Items[0].
            Get<Dicom.DicomSequence>(Dicom.DicomTag.ControlPointSequence).Items[0].
            Get<Dicom.DicomSequence>(Dicom.DicomTag.BeamLimitingDevicePositionSequence).Items[0].
            Get<Dicom.DicomElement>(Dicom.DicomTag.LeafJawPositions);
```

But `string` isn't able to accept `Dicom.DicomElement` as a string and with `Get<string>()` in the last line I only get the cut string again.

Hoping you can help to find where I did something wrong and how to get the full string of this item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/issues/491 they are fixing the issue with a new API, but assuming you are using an older release,

```
string Leaf = String.Join(@"\",
              ...
              Get<string[]>(Dicom.DicomTag.LeafJawPositions));
```

should return what you expect.

PS I use a `string` extension method for `Join`:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string sep) => String.Join(sep, strings.ToArray());
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, char sep) => String.Join(sep.ToString(), strings.ToArray());
```