# Split string with multiple separators in C#

Tags: c#

I am having trouble splitting a string in C# with a delimiters `&&` and `||`.

For example the string could look like:

```
"(abc)&&(rfd)&&(5)||(hh)&&(nn)||(iu)"
```

Code:

```
string[] value = arguments.Split(new string[] { "&&" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I need to split or retrieve values in array without `()` braces - I need thte output to be

```
"abc" "rfd" "5" "nn" "iu"
```

and I need it in an array

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("a", "value1");
            dict.Add("abc", "value2");
            dict.Add("5", "value3");
            dict.Add("rfd", "value4");
            dict.Add("nn", "value5");
            dict.Add("iu", "value6");

foreach (string s in strWithoutBrackets)
{
     foreach (string n in dict.Keys)
     {
          if (s == n)
          { 
               //if match then replace dictionary value with s
          }
      }
}

 ///Need output like this
 string outputStr = "(value1)&&(value2)&&(value3)||(value4)&&(value5)||(value6)";
```

Comment: And the expected output is.?

Comment: Why have you got spaces around the `&&` in `" && "`?

Comment: You can write your own parser - or look into regular expressions.

Comment: What's not working with what you have already done?

Comment: i am getting array with || ()

Comment: @John - Why do you expect `new string[] { "&&" }` to remove `||` and `(` and `)`? Isn't it then fairly obvious what you need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Split A String By Another String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/c-sharp-split-a-string-by-another-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a string like this:

```
"(abc)&&(rfd)&&(5)||(hh)&&(nn)||(iu)"
```

and want output like this:

```
"(value1)&&(value2)&&(value3)||(value4)&&(value5)||(value6)"
```

Where each of the `value*` values is found by looking up a matched string (for instance `"abc"`) in a dictionary you supply.

If that is the case you can use a regular expression with a [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) that does the dictionary lookup.

```
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"a", "value1"},
        {"abc", "value2"},
        {"5", "value3"},
        {"rfd", "value4"},
        {"nn", "value5"},
        {"iu", "value6"}
    };

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = "(abc)&&(rfd)&&(5)||(hh)&&(nn)||(iu)";

        string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\()\w+(?=\))", Lookup);

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }

    private static string Lookup(Match m)
    {
        string result;
        _dict.TryGetValue(m.Value, out result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

The regex `(?<=\()\w+(?=\))` matches a non zero length string consisting of upper or lower cases letters, the underscore or digits: `\w+`, a look behind assertion for the opening parenthesis `(?<=\()` and a look ahead assertion for the closing parenthesis `(?=\))`.

Note that one of the strings that is matched in the input string `"hh"` is not in the dictionary you supply. I have chosen to return `null` in that case, you might want to throw an exception or handle such an error in another way.

In simple cases, the `MatchEvaluator` can be replaced by a lambda expression.

Answer (score 7):

You should try these:

```
string inputStr = "(abc)&&(rfd)&&(5)||(hh)&&(nn)||(iu)";
string[] strWithoutAndOR = inputStr.Split(new string[] { "&&","||" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] strWithoutBrackets = inputStr.Split(new string[] { "&&","||","(",")" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Check out this [working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9x6kyF)

> As per MSDN docs: [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) Returns a string array that
>   contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by
>   elements of a specified string or Unicode character array. The split
>   method is having few overloaded methods, you can make use of
>   [String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) for this
>   scenario, where you can specify the subStrings that you want to refer for the split operation. The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will helps you to remove empty entries from the split result

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("a", "value1");
            dict.Add("abc", "value2");
            dict.Add("5b", "value3");
            dict.Add("hh", "value4");
            dict.Add("nn", "value5");
            dict.Add("iu", "value6");

Comment: @John: Well, have you checked my code, working example?

Comment: foreach (string s in strWithoutBrackets)
            {
                foreach (string n in dict.Keys)
                {
                    if (s == n)
                    { 
                       //if match then replace dictionary value with s
                    }
                }
            }

            ///Need output like this
            string outputStr = "(value1)&&(value2)&&(value3)||(value4)&&(value5)||(value6)";

Comment: thanks lucky it works i just want to match arrary value with dictionary and make a new string please check updated question

Comment: Probably that would be a different question. anyway what's wrong with that

Comment: ya thasts different question but i need to replace dictionay key value if match array and form a new string

Comment: @John: It needs a different approach. Since you need to add the removed brackets, && and || back to the new string. Which means a replacement is needed to perform on the initial string for each matching keys

Answer (score -3):

You should try this code :

```
string value = "(abc)&&(rfd)&&(5)||(hh)&&(nn)||(iu)";
string[] splitVal = value.Split(new string[] { "&&", "||" },StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: It doesn't do what the OP wants. And why have you got the `string[] a = splitVal;;`?

Comment: string[] a is just for testing purpose. now it's correct.

Comment: Your answer still doesn't do what the OP wants.