# Split String includes spaces

Tags: vb.net, split

I have a string in the form of `myText = "1000 - abc 123 xyz"`

When I do `myText.split(" - ")(0)` I get the value 1000, but `myText.split(" - ")(1)` I get the value "-", and `myText.split(" - ")(2)` = "abc"

If I remove the spaces so `myText = "1000-abc 123 xyz"`, `myText.split("-")(1)` = "abc 123 xyz" as required.

Thought the split character was not included in the array, and why are the spaces influencing the outcome when the are part of the split value.

Comment: You cannot split like this: `myText.Split(" - ")`. There's no overload of `string.Split()` that accepts these arguments. You have use an array of strings: `myText.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. It will return an array of 2 elements, which will not include the separator, of course.

Comment: Option Strict Off doing its usual evil deeds, you are getting the String.Split(Char()) overload.  So it will split on spaces as well.  With Option Strict On at the top of the source file you'll get a decent compile error message.

Comment: Thanks for your help both. Understand now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string by another string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/split-a-string-by-another-string-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot split like this: `myText.Split(" - ")`. There's no overload of `string.Split()` that accepts these arguments. You have use an array of strings: `myText.Split({" - "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`. It will return an array of 2 elements, which will not include the separator, of course.

Answered by Jimi in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58626642/split-string-includes-spaces/68828932#comment103560987_58626642).