# how to split string base on "\r\n" in c# when string value have "\r\n\r\n"

Tags: c#

i have this string

```
var str="\r\nFeatures\r\nWins\r\n\r\n";
```

i want split on `"\r\n"` but between two "\r\n\r\n" have value null or whitespace

i want get result 3 items = `Features Wins nullorwhitespace`

i write this code but get 2 items =  `Features Wins`

```
var val = str.TrimStart('\r', '\n', '\t').TrimEnd('\r', '\n', '\t').Split("\r\n");
```

Comment: `var result = str.Split(new[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(s => !s.Equals("\r")).ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

Easy option would be to just replace "\r\n\r\n" with whatever you want to see in between and then split.

```
var val = str
       .Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\nempty\r\n")
       .Split(new []{"\r\n"}, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current code is that the `TrimEnd` call gets rid of all of the trailing `\r\n` characters.

```
str.TrimStart('\r', '\n', '\t') // "Features\r\nWins\r\n\r\n"
   .TrimEnd('\r', '\n', '\t') // "Features\r\nWins"
   .Split("\r\n"); // ["Features", "Wins"]
```

For your example text you could do the following to get the result you want. It wont work depending on what you want to do with tabs though:

```
var str="\r\nFeatures\r\nWins\r\n\r\n";

var val = str.TrimStart('\r') // "\nFeatures\r\nWins\r\n\r\n"
             .TrimStart('\n') // "Features\r\nWins\r\n\r\n"
             .TrimEnd('\n') // "Features\r\nWins\r\n\r"
             .TrimEnd('\r') // "Features\r\nWins\r\n"
             .Split("\r\n"); // ["Features, "Wins", ""]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this one as well. It also keeps the `""` characters at the beginning and at the end, but they can be excluded by deleting the first and last elements of the resulting array:

```
var array = str.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None); // 
array = ["","Features","","Wins",""]
```

Here is the reference link: [Split a string by another string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/split-a-string-by-another-string-in-c-sharp)