# Sort list by price c#

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list based on the price for each item in the list.

Here's what I want my output to look like:

```
            ROLLS_ROYCE1 -- 6.608 €
            ROLLS_ROYCE3 -- 4.956 €
            ROLLS_ROYCE2 -- 0.826 €
```

However, here's what the current output actually is:

```
            ROLLS_ROYCE1 -- 6.608 €
            ROLLS_ROYCE2 -- 0.82 €
            ROLLS_ROYCE3 -- 4.956 €
```

Here's my code:

```
public void MyFunction() 
{
   List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[]
   {
      "ROLLS_ROYCE1 -- 0,826 € -- 8 PCS -- 14:02:53.876",
      "ROLLS_ROYCE2 -- 0,826 € -- 1 PCS -- 17:02:53.888",
      "ROLLS_ROYCE3 -- 0,826 € -- 6 PCS -- 18:09:55.888"
   });

   foreach (string f in mylist)
   {
      decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(GetPrice(f), CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")) * Convert.ToDecimal(GetPieces(f));
      tradesforbigbuyslist += GetName(f) + " -- " + b.ToString() + " €" + 
         Environment.NewLine;
   }

   string[] splittedt2 = tradesforbigbuyslist.Split(new string[] { 
   System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            
   listBox3.DataSource = splittedt2;
}

public string GetPrice (string sourceline)
{
   string newstring = sourceline;
   string test1 = newstring.Replace(FetchThemAll.SubstringExtensions.Before(newstring, "--"), "");
   string textIWant = test1.Replace("--", "");
   string finalPrice = FetchThemAll.SubstringExtensions.Before(textIWant, "€");


   return finalPrice;
}

public string GetPieces(string sourceline)
{
   string ertzu = sourceline;
   string ertzu1 = FetchThemAll.SubstringExtensions.Between(ertzu, "€", "PCS");
   string ertzu2 = ertzu1.Replace("--", "");

   return ertzu2;
}

public string GetName(string sourceline)
{
   string barno = FetchThemAll.SubstringExtensions.Before(sourceline, "--");

   return barno;
}
```

How can I sort these strings correctly?

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting of your code a little bit. It looked like you were missing the start of your code (there was an unmatched closing bracket `}` on the line after `listBox3.DataSource = splittedt2;`, implying that it was the end of a method, but the start of the method was not in your original question). So, I put it inside a function called `MyFunction` - but please feel free to change it to your actual method name.

Comment: thx a lot buddy @Donut

Comment: Why not try creating a class that stores these values as properties and represent each line as an object. Then a simple linq query could do this and also generate the output.

Comment: To help you fix your code, we probably need to see `SubstringExtensions` -- i.e., a [mcve].  However, can't you just split the `"ROLLS_ROYCE1 -- 0,826 € -- 8 PCS -- 14:02:53.876"` strings using the `" -- "` substring using [`string.Split(String, StringSplitOptions)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Split_System_String_System_StringSplitOptions_)?  See: [Split a string by another string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2245442/3744182).  You can also split the `0,826 €` and `8 PCS` substrings using the same approach.

Comment: Agreed about creating a class, since you're already parsing the string anyway, may as well parse it into a type with a `string Name`, `decimal Price`, `int Quantity`, and `DateTime OrderTime` (or `TimeSpan`? not sure what the last field is).

Comment: I tried that by doing OrderByDescending but didnt work, actually my code works, its just that feature which i need barely, its just about sorting it from now here

Comment: *I tried that by doing OrderByDescending but didnt work* -- Then can you please [edit] your code to share a [mcve] -- specifically the code that didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify a lot of this work by representing each line of input as a class with relevant properties like this. If accuracy is super important like with dealing real money then fixed precision data type should represent the price. However I am using double below for simplicity.

```
public class Car {
    public string Name;
    public short Pieces;
    public double Price;
}
```

Then you would parse them at the beginning and have a list of these Car items. Assuming the Price above represents the desired value you wish to sort by the list you seek would be obtained by the following linq query.

```
var cars = new List<Cars>(); //Assumed definition
var frenchCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"); //For Euros symbol usage later
//Parse Logic in Between
var sortedCars = cars.OrderByDescending(c => c.Price); //Linq Query yielding IEnumerable. If you must have a list simply append toList()
```

Then your output might be set like this.

```
foreach (var car in sortedCars)
    // output with string.format("{0} -- {1}", car.Name, car.Price.ToString("C3", frenchCulture))
```

Warning that this code was not tested but should be approximately correct. I did do some research for the string format.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the format of your strings in `mylist` looks consistent enough that something like this might work (without using extension methods or Regex at all):

```
var parsed = mylist.Select(line => line.Split(new[] { " -- " }, StringSplitOptions.None)).Select(parts => new
{
   Name = parts[0],
   Price = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[1].Substring(0, parts[1].IndexOf(' '))),
   Pieces = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2].Substring(0, parts[2].IndexOf(' ')))
});

var sorted = parsed.OrderByDescending(x => x.Price * x.Pieces);
```

Then you can do whatever you want with `sorted` - e.g. convert the items back to strings and display them in `listBox3`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, unfortunately I cant compile, following error                               
  ` var parsed = mylist.Select(line => line.Split(" -- ")).Select(parts => new `Cannot convert string into char ` @donut

Comment: @HassanBelHaq try `line.Split(new [] { " -- " }, StringSplitOptions.None)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did: I have tested this and it seems to work.

```
    public void MyFunction() 
{
   List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[]
   {
      "ROLLS_ROYCE1 -- 0,826 € -- 8 PCS -- 14:02:53.876",
      "ROLLS_ROYCE2 -- 0,826 € -- 1 PCS -- 17:02:53.888",
      "ROLLS_ROYCE3 -- 0,826 € -- 6 PCS -- 18:09:55.888"
   });
   
   var map = new Dictionary<string, double>();
   foreach (string f in mylist)
   {
      var inputs = f.Split(" -- "); //Creates a list of strings

      var unitPrice = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[1].Split(' ')[0]);
      var numUnits = Convert.ToDouble(inputs[2].Split(' ')[0]);
       
      var key = inputs[0];
      if(map.ContainsKey(key)) map[key] = numUnits*unitPrice;
      else map.Add(key, numUnits*unitPrice);      
   }

   var sortedMap = map.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value);

   foreach(var item in sortedMap){
     Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} -- {item.Value} €");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be overkill for you, but what I usually do in cases like this is create a class that knows how to parse one of those lines into strongly typed properties, like `Name`, `Price`, `Quantity`, etc. Usually I create a `static` method named `Price` that takes in an `input` string and returns an instance of the class.

In this case it would look something like:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Total => Price * Quantity;

    public static Item Parse(string input)
    {
        if (input==null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        var parts = input
            .Split(new[] {"--", " ", "€", "PCS"}, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (parts.Length != 4)
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Input must contain 4 sections separated by \"--\"");

        decimal price;
        if (!decimal.TryParse(parts[1], out price))
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Price must be a valid decimal in the second position");

        int quantity;
        if (!int.TryParse(parts[2], out quantity))
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Quantity must be a valid integer in the third position");

        TimeSpan time;
        if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(parts[3], out time))
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "Time must be a valid TimeSpan in the fourth position");

        return new Item
        {
            Name = parts[0],
            Price = price,
            Quantity = quantity,
            Time = time
        };
    }
}
```

With the work being done in the class, our main code is simplified tremendously:

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>(new string[]
{
    "ROLLS_ROYCE1 -- 0,826 € -- 8 PCS -- 14:02:53.876",
    "ROLLS_ROYCE2 -- 0,826 € -- 1 PCS -- 17:02:53.888",
    "ROLLS_ROYCE3 -- 0,826 € -- 6 PCS -- 18:09:55.888"
});

List<Item> orderedItems = mylist
    .Select(Item.Parse)
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Total)
    .ToList();
```

And then displaying the items would be as simple as:

```
orderedItems.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} -- {item.Total} €"));
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: works fine only the calculated prices arent formated properly for me ( using net 4.5) , do I have to use CultureInfo or something similiar? @RufusL

Comment: In what way are they not formulated properly? I had to change the commas to periods in the original strings since periods are the decimal separator in the US. What are you seeing in your culture?

Comment: I am seeing only numbers for example 6608 or 4956, I am from Germany

Comment: Are those the correct numbers and you just want to add the thousands separator? Or are they not the correct numbers at all? You might try formatting them as currency: `$"{kvp.Key}={kvp.Value:C}"`