# Method not returning correct number of integers when counting a keyword in a string

Tags: c#

was doing a method on counting the recurrences of a certain word in a string.

this is how it should work:

Input: "I really like the color of the light of the sun, when the sun is high in the sky", count how many times the word "the" is within that sentence.
Output: "The word "the" was found 5 times"

Did this without a method directly on the main and worked. However in a method it always returns 0 to me. Here is my code.

```
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string firstEx = "I really like the color of the light of the sun, when the sun is high in the sky";
        string[] yuh = firstEx.Split(' ');
        string word = "the";
        int counter = 0;
        int res = CountWord(firstEx, word, ref counter);
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }

    static int CountWord(string statement, string keyWord, ref int count)
    {
        keyWord = "";
        count = 0;
        string[] splitStat = statement.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < splitStat.Length; i++)
        {
            if (splitStat[i] == keyWord)
            {
                count++;
            }
            
        }
        return count;
    }


}
```

Comment: Because of the `keyWord = ""`? You also don't need the `ref int count`.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No its not homework.
@GSerg What should the keyword="" be set to in this case?

Comment: `keyWord = "";` will always set keyord to an empty sting, then `splitStat[i] == keyWord` will only match an empty string, your essentially doing `splitStat[i] == ""`. Remove `keyWord = "";`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245442/split-a-string-by-another-string-in-c-sharp#2245460

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
keyWord = "";
```

You are pretty much overwriting the passed variable for the function. If you remove that, your code will work fine.