# Regex How to Match 2 fields

Tags: c#, regex

How would capture both the filenames inside the quotes, and the numbers following as named captures (Regex / C#)?

```
Files("fileone.txt", 5969784, "file2.txt", 45345333)
```

Out of every occurrence in the string, the ability to capture "fileone.txt" and the integer following (a loop cycles each pair)

I am trying to use this https://regex101.com/r/MwMzBo/1 but having issues matching without the '[' and ']'.

Required to be able to loop each filename+size as a pair and moving next.

Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

```
string file = "Files(\"fileone.txt\", 5969784, \"file2.txt\", 45345333, \"file2.txt\", 45345333)";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\w+\()(?:""(?<file>.*?)""|'(?<file>.*?)')\s*,\s*(?<number>\d+)");
var match = regex.Match(file);
var names = match.Groups["file"].Captures.Cast<Capture>();
var lengths = match.Groups["number"].Captures.Cast<Capture>();
var filelist = names.Zip(lengths, (f, n) => new { file = f.Value, length = long.Parse(n.Value) }).ToArray();
foreach (var item in filelist)
{
   // Only returning 1 pair result, ignoring the rest
}
```

[image]

*Reading match.Value to confirm what is being read.* Only first pair is being picked up.

```
while (match.Success)
{
   MessageBox.Show(match.Value);
   match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Now we are getting all results properly. I read, that Regex.Match only returns the first matched result. This explains a lot.

Comment: Where are you getting the filename and integer from?

Comment: It is generated using a FileInfo instance and added to a string in a loop

Comment: do you have this line: `"Files("fileone.txt", 5969784, "file2.txt", 45345333)"` accessible in form of a `string` ?

Comment: Yes I do. I it is available locally and I have it as a string to test

Comment: What is your regex? Show it in the question ([edit] the question), not via a link to another website.

Comment: im using ```(?<=([""']\b))(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?(?=\1)```

Comment: What regex are you using? There are different regexes in the comment and in the body of the question. Please see [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444808/546871) for one way to better understand what has been captured by a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\w+\()(?:""(?<file>.*?)""|'(?<file>.*?)')\s*,\s*(?<number>\d+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1QulEl/3)

*Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!\A)\s*,\s*|\w+\()` - end of the previous successful match and a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces, or a word and an opening `(` char
- `(?:""(?<file>.*?)""|'(?<file>.*?)')` - `"`, Group "file" capturing any zero or more chars other than a newline char as few as possible and then a `"`, or a `'`, Group "file" capturing any zero or more chars other than a newline char as few as possible and then a `'`
- `\s*,\s*` - a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `(?<number>\d+)` - Group "number": one or more digits.

Comment: Thanks is exactly what wanted. Thank you. When using the expression and using the named groups in a foreach loop, I only get the first file and number values (looping results to a listview control). Not sure if that is intended or not. If the string had 33 files and 33 number fields, each pair must be available as a single iteration - obtaining "file" and "number" fields respectively.

Comment: @WLFree Just FYI, [here is the C# demo](https://ideone.com/G2J0qL).

Comment: Wow.. that is bang on! Just a question.. will this support a huge amount results? (say, like 80 files in that string)?

Comment: @WLFree Sure, it will.

Answer (score 0):

I like doing it in smaller pieces :

```
            string input =  "cov('Age', ['5','7','9'])";
            string pattern1 = @"\((?'key'[^,]+),\s+\[(?'values'[^\]]+)";

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern1);
            string key = match.Groups["key"].Value.Trim(new char[] {'\''});
            string pattern2 = @"'(?'value'[^']+)'";
            string values = match.Groups["values"].Value;
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(values, pattern2);
            int[] number = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value.Replace("'",string.Empty))).ToArray();
```