# C# how to separate by paragraph?

Tags: c#, streamreader, text-files

so I know a paragraph is char 10 + char 13 
I do:

```
streamreader sr = new streamreader();
string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
string s1 = s.Replace((char)10, "*");
string s2 = s1.Replace((char)13, "*");
```

Now it changed paragraphs to two ** but how do I split by 2 chars? Anyone have any alternatives to splitting paragraphs?

1. way of easily splitting paragraphs 
   OR
2. way of splitting by two chars

Comment: possible duplicate of [string.split - by multiple character delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter)

Answer (score 5):

```
string doc = "line1\r\nline2\r\nline3";
var docLines = doc.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Alliteratively you could use Environment.NewLine... which would keep things standard.

```
var docLines = doc.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean ASCII cr+lf (13+10), just use [StreamReader.ReadLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `Regex`? Windows uses `\r`(13) folowed by `\n`(10) as a line separator, so you would get lines. But if you want blocks of text separated by at least one empty line, you might try this:

```
 string inputString = sr.ReadToEnd();

 string[] paragraphs = Regex.Split(inputString , "(\r\n){2,}");
```

Answer (score 1):

See [string.Split(string[], StringSplitOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
var result = s2.Split(new []{"**"}, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Also you can do it by using [Environment.NewLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx), without convert it to **:

```
var result = s.Split(new []{Enviornment.NewLine}, StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: The problem with the ** is that he is copying it into 2 more strings to make that happen... if that file was large it would eat memory like crazy, thus I would avoid the ** approach completely.

Comment: @CrazyDart, I wrote both ways before your comment and your answer, Also I just edit it to add link to msdn document.(again before your comment)

Comment: I dont debate that, all I am saying is that the OP should not use the ** method because of the heavy lifting.  Its not optimal.  I am guessing the only reason that was done was to reveal the \r\n.  In the end, Mithrandir may have the better answer... the regex engine will likely work faster.

Comment: @CrazyDart, I'm agree with you. but is good for OP to knoe it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression if your splitting criteria is simple.