# C# Parse CSV with quoted text that have fields with quoes

Tags: c#, parsing, text, csv

I have a CSV file that all fields have quoted text.  My problem is that I have quotes within quotes as follows.

```
"John Doe","I have a 17" screen","Something "A" something else",....
```

I have tried Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO and LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv and both are not allowing quotes within those fields.

Comment: The embedded should be doubled, e.g. `"I have a 17"" screen"` to be properly formatted, which is why the libraries are having trouble parsing it.  If you don't control the source you will have to parse the string manually.

Answer (score 2):

If you are don't have an option to do proper double quotes in the source files and need to parse this manually, this might help you:

```
var split = theCsv.Split(',');
var noQuotesCollection = split.Select(p =>
{
    if (p.StartsWith("\"") && p.EndsWith("\"") && p.Length > 1)
        return p.Substring(1, p.Length - 2);
    return p;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have quotes in a CSV file you have to use double quotes.

Here is a sample

"here is some text","here is some more text","here is some text with a quotation, ""Hello World"""

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried splitting the string on "," ? Assuming that's consistent throughout your file that should work. Of course, if you have an internal "," within a field you're out of luck.

Check [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter) for an example of splitting on multiple characters.