# Conditional Split String with multiple delimiters

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, delimiter

I have a String

```cs
string astring="#This is a Section*This is the first category*This is the
second Category# This is another Section";
```

I want to separate this string according to delimiters. If I have # at the start this will indicate Section string (string[] section). If the string will starts with * this will indicate that I have a category(string[] category).
As a result I want to have

```
string[] section = { "This is a Section", "This is another Section" }; 
string[] category = { "This is the first category ",
     "This is the second Category " };
```

I have found this answer:
[string.split - by multiple character delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter)
But it is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: Looks like a job for a regular expression to me, using capturing groups that should be a walk in the park

Comment: @SimonRapilly You don't even need capturing groups. Matches are enough.

Comment: True enough, if you have two regexs like in your answer, but if you want a single regex then you will need capturing groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string astring=@"#This is a Section*This is the first category*This is the second Category# This is another Section";

string[] sections = Regex.Matches(astring, @"#([^\*#]*)").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
string[] categories = Regex.Matches(astring, @"\*([^\*#]*)").Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thak you for the great solution

Answer (score 0):

With string.Split You could do this (faster than the regex ;) )

```
List<string> sectionsResult = new List<string>();
List<string> categorysResult = new List<string>();
string astring="#This is a Section*This is the first category*This is thesecond Category# This is another Section";

var sections = astring.Split('#').Where(i=> !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i));

foreach (var section in sections)
{
    var sectieandcategorys =  section.Split('*');
    sectionsResult.Add(sectieandcategorys.First());
    categorysResult.AddRange(sectieandcategorys.Skip(1));
}
```

Comment: I take an error  "string does not contain a definition for split"