# split a string into 2 arrays based on 2 delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, arrays, string, split

I want to split a string into 2 arrays, one with the text that's delimited by vbTab (I think it's `\t` in c#) and another string with the test thats delimited by vbtab (I think it's `\n` in c#).

By searching I found this ([StackOverFlow Question: 1254577](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter)):

```
string input = "abc][rfd][5][,][.";
string[] parts1 = input.Split(new string[] { "][" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string[] parts2 = Regex.Split(input, @"\]\[");
```

but my string would be something like this:

```
aaa\tbbb\tccc\tddd\teee\nAccount\tType\tCurrency\tBalance\t123,456.78\nDate\tDetails\tAmount\n03NOV13\tTransfer\t9,999,999.00-\n02NOV13\t\Cheque\t125.00\nDebit Card Cash\t200.00
```

so in the above code **input** becomes:

```
string input = "aa\tbbb\tccc\tddd\teee\nAccount\tType\tPersonal Current Account\tCurrency\tGBP\tBalance\t123,456.78\nDate\tDetails\tAmount\n03NOV13\tTransfer\t9,999,999.00-\n02NOV13\t\Cheque\t125.00\nDebit Card Cash\t200.00\n30OCT13\tLoan Repayment\t1,234.56-\n\tType\t30-Day Notice Savings Account\tCurrency\tGBP\tBalance\t983,456.78\nDate\tDetails\tAmount\n03NOV13\tRepaid\t\250\n"
```

but how do I create one string array with everthing up to the first **newline** and another array that holds everything after?

Then the second one will have to be split again into several string arrays so I can write out a mini-statement with the account details, then showing the transactions for each account.

I want to be able to take the original string and produce something like this on A5 paper:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide exepected arrays' items, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a LINQ query:

```
        var cells = from row in input.Split('\n')
                    select row.Split('\t');
```

You can get just the first row using `First()` and the remaining rows using `Skip()`. For example:

```
        foreach (string s in cells.First())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First: " + s);
        }
```

Or

```
        foreach (string[] row in cells.Skip(1))
        {
             Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do what you requested. This resulted in `part1` having 5 entries and `part2` having 26 entries

```cs
string input = "aa\tbbb\tccc\tddd\teee\nAccount\tType\tPersonal Current Account\tCurrency\tGBP\tBalance\t123,456.78\nDate\tDetails\tAmount\n03NOV13\tTransfer\t9,999,999.00-\n02NOV13\t\Cheque\t125.00\nDebit Card Cash\t200.00\n30OCT13\tLoan Repayment\t1,234.56-\n\tType\t30-Day Notice Savings Account\tCurrency\tGBP\tBalance\t983,456.78\nDate\tDetails\tAmount\n03NOV13\tRepaid\t\250\n";

// Substring starting at 0 and ending where the first newline begins
string input1 = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(@"\n"));

/* Substring starting where the first newline begins
   plus the length of the new line  to the end */
string input2 = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(@"\n") + 2);

string[] part1 = Regex.Split(input1, @"\\t");
string[] part2 = Regex.Split(input2, @"\\t");
```