# Multi-Character Split does not work

Tags: vb.net

I have the following string:

```
"367","90","Hey, this is a "cool" company","","","Anonymous"
```

I want to get this separted into a string array so according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter) I tried

```
Dim strSource As String = """367"",""90"",""Hey, this is a "cool" company"","""","""",""Anonymous"""
Dim parts As String() = strSource.Split(New String() {"", ""}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

but something seems wrong since I get only one string element instead of six I want to:

```
 1. 367
 2. 90
 3. Hey, this is a "cool" company
 4. 
 5. 
 6. Anonymous
```

Comment: Maybe it's a typo but the split separtor has a blank, and the string hasn't it. "", "" -> "",""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't phrased the string split pattern correctly:

```
Dim strSource As String = """367"",""90"",""Hey, this is a ""cool"" company"","""","""",""Anonymous"""
Dim parts As String() = strSource.Split(New String() {""","""}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```