# How to use (?!...) regex pattern to skip the whole unmatched part?

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to use the `((?!(SEPARATOR)).)*` regex pattern for splitting a string.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var separator = "__";
        var pattern = String.Format("((?!{0}).)*", separator);
        var regex = new Regex(pattern);

        foreach (var item in regex.Matches("first__second"))
            Console.WriteLine(item);        
    }
}
```

It works fine when a `SEPARATOR` is a single character, but when it is longer then 1 character I get an unexpected result. In the code above the second matched string is "_second" instead of "second". How shall I modify my pattern to skip the whole unmatched separator?

My real problem is to split lines where I should skip line separators inside quotes. My line separator is not a predefined value and it can be for example "\r\n".

Comment: No, just split with that pattern. If it is a regex pattern, use `Regex.Split`, if it is a literal fixed string like `__`, just use `string.Split`. You won't be able to achieve what you want by *matching* in a .NET regex. In PCRE, you would use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs, but they are not supported in .NET.

Comment: Why not use `string.Split` for this ? Ex. `"first__second".Split(new[] { "__" }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: I would like to use regex because my pattern is more complicated. String.Split is not enough for my purpose.

Comment: And what is your *real* problem then? Right now, your question is a dupe of [string.split - by multiple character delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter).

Comment: My real problem is to split lines where I should skip line separators inside quotes. My line separator is not a predefined value and it can be for example "\r\n".

Comment: So, the real scenario differs from what you posted a lot. Try `Regex.Matches(s, "(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\r\n\"])+")`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string input = "plum--pear";
      string pattern = "-";            // Split on hyphens

      string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
      foreach (string match in substrings)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
      }
   }
}


// The method displays the following output:
//    'plum'
//    ''
//    'pear'
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET regex does not does not support matching a piece of text other than a specific multicharacter string. In PCRE, you would use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs, but they are not supported in the native .NET regex library. Surely, you might want to use PCRE.NET, but .NET regex can usually handle those scenarios well with `Regex.Split`

If you need to, say, match all but `[anything here]`, you could use

```
var res = Regex.Split(s, @"\[[^][]*]").Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m));
```

If the separator is a simple literal fixed string like `__`, just use `String.Split`.

As for your *real* problem, it seems all you need is

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, "(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\r\n\"])+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%22%5B%5E%22%5D*%22%7C%5B%5E%5Cr%5Cn%22%5D%29%2B&i=Text%20%0D%0AOn%20a%20Line%20%22but%0D%0Anot%20inside%20quotes%22%20yes%0D%0Ahere)

It matches 1+ (due to the final `+`) occurrences of `"`, 0+ chars other than `"` and then `"` (the `"[^"]*"` branch) or (`|`) any char but CR, LF or/and `"` (see `[^\r\n"]`).