# Ambiguous match found when calling String.Split()

Tags: ambiguous, jscript.net

I'm programming in **JScript.NET** which is similar to **C#** . I want to split a string on multiple characters, in this case " - ".

The problem is when I do that like this (which should be the way to do it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter) thread):

```
var text = "test - test2";

var array = [" - "];

var val = text.Split(array, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I get "Ambiguous match found". This is because the String class has both a `Split(Char[], StringSplitOptions)` and a `Split(String[], StringSplitOptions)` function, and the compiler doesn't know which one to use.

So my question is then. How do I tell the compiler that I'm using a string array when the arrays in JScript.NET are dynamically typed?

Edit: As far as I know, **JScript.NET use the same APIs as C#**. So [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2.) is the String class I'm using. However, I think the syntax is the same as JavaScript. Maybe someone could confirm this?

Edit2: So if there is a way to enforce a type in JScript.NET so the compiler knows which type is used, I guess that would be the answer for my case as well? JScript.NET does not have the same syntax as C#.

Comment: The code you posted is for C#.

Comment: With plain Javascript, you should be able to split your string calling `text.split(array);`

Comment: @Cheloide Well this is the code I use in JScript, which I thought had the same syntax as JavaScript (according to Wikipedia, I don't really have any experience with JavaScript myself). The String class that is used is this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2, which I guess, as you point out, is the same as in C#.

Comment: There are no types in JavaScript, so JScript is probably less similar to JavaScript that you might think.

Comment: Jscript is a dynamically typed language as far as I know. That's why I'm really confused about the function saying that it's input is ambiguous.

Comment: @JonatanStenbacka [JScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) is not [JScript.net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET)

Comment: @Cheloide Aha... Thanks for clarifying that! I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out once I realized I was coding in JScript.NET and not JScript, which led me to a bunch of useful guides. One of them specifically mentioned [how to create typed arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/5kas1c51%28v%3Dvs.100%29).

It turns out it was a easy as this:

```
var array : String[] = [" -"];
```