# How to pass array of delimiters to Regex.Split function?

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, split

As the title indicates, how can I pass an array of delimiters to a Regex.Split function? I'm needing to split a sentence (string) by a list of words (also strings).

Comment: Can you post sample input and sample strings to split by? Maybe, also, the code you've tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string.split - by multiple character delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254577/string-split-by-multiple-character-delimiter)

Comment: Lookup alternations.

Comment: In `String.Split` you can pass an array of delimiters; however, not in `Regex.Split`. Instead, you pass a regex expression describing a search pattern for split positions. It can be as simple as `string[] parts = Regex.Split(input, "a|b|c");` This would split on the 3 characters "a" to "c". You should probably use `String.Split`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a regex pattern from "delimiter" words like this:

```
var delim = new string[] {"fox", "lazy"};
var pattern =  @"(?:\s|^)(?:" + string.Join("|", delim.Select(Regex.Escape)) + @")(?:\s|$)";
```

`\s` and string anchors at the beginning and at the end ensure that delimiters include all white space around them, and that you avoid the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem). Using `Regex.Espace` ensures that delimiters with regex meta-characters do not break your code.

The resultant pattern looks as follows:

```
(?:\s|^)(?:fox|lazy)(?:\s|$)
```

[Demo 1](http://ideone.com/WHugCt)

If you would like to keep delimiter words among the tokens, change regex to use them in a lookahead/lookbehind:

```
var delimGroup = "(?:"+string.Join("|", delim.Select(Regex.Escape))+")";
var pattern =  @"\s(?="+delimGroup+")|(?<="+delimGroup+@")\s";
```

[Demo 2](http://ideone.com/0LAo9q)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That seems to be what I'm looking for.. is there any way I can preserver the delimiters in the final result? At the moment the `fox` and `lazy` ar excluded from the final string...